# Spark Parquet : Getting issue in infer schema as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid DECIMAL scale: -1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, parquet

Spark version 2.4.0
Cluster : AWS EMR

I am reading tsv.gz input file into spark dataframe and when trying to store it back, with or without some transformation, having infer schema true I am getting exception as given below,

```
tsv_data = spark. \
    read. \
    format("csv"). \
    option("delimiter", "\t"). \
    option("header", "true"). \
    option("inferSchema", "true"). \
    load("s3://<location>"). \
    repartition("somedatecolumn")


tsv_data.write.parquet("s3://<some-location>")
```

Getting below exception

```
[Stage 8:=================================================>         (5 + 1) / 6]19/09/04 15:02:06 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 430, ip-10-219-46-138.awsuw2.seagate.com, executor 12): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid DECIMAL scale: -1
        at org.apache.parquet.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:53)
        at org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$BasePrimitiveBuilder.decimalMetadata(Types.java:495)
        at org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$BasePrimitiveBuilder.build(Types.java:403)
        at org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$BasePrimitiveBuilder.build(Types.java:309)
        at org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$Builder.named(Types.java:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SparkToParquetSchemaConverter.convertField(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SparkToParquetSchemaConverter.convertField(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SparkToParquetSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:326)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SparkToParquetSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:326)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.map(StructType.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SparkToParquetSchemaConverter.convert(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:326)
```

However when I am writing it into csv then able to run it successfully.

```py
tsv_data.write.csv("s3://<some-location>")
```

Let me know if anyone has any solutions.

Additional info about the data is, I am having double value in one of the columns as 2.0190814055629E+15.  (just taken one row from millions of records)

One more update: I am getting decimal(15,-1) while doing printSchama(). Can we selectively suppress infer schema for few columns ?

Comment: i have experienced the same problem when inferring schema ... the only fix i found was to manually cast the corrupt columns to ```double```

Comment: @thePurplePython, yes I did the same for time being. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid schema inference, it reads in the entire file just to try and work out the schema. Do it once on a sample. use the results of that to define the schema in code and choose the real datatypes you want.